# str_getcsv to an associative array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following code that generates a very nice indexed array -

```
<?php
// reads csv file and returns an array of rows
function read_csv($filename){
$rows = array();
foreach (file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $line){
$rows[] = str_getcsv($line, $delimiter = '; ', $escape = '\''); 
} 
return $rows;
}        
?>
```

Output looks like -

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                [0] => value
                [1] => value
                [2] => value
                [3] => value
                [4] => value
                [5] => value
                [6] => value
                [7] => value
                [8] => value
                [9] => value
                [10] => value
                [11] => value
                [12] => value
                [13] => value
                [14] => value
                [15] => value
                [16] => value
                [17] => value
                [18] => value
                [19] => value
                [20] => value
)
```

Is it possible to set the pointers of the internal array to look something like this -

```
Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [label 1] => value
                [label 1] => value
                [label 2] => value
                [label 3] => value
                [label 4] => value
                [label 5] => value
                [label 6] => value
                [label 7] => value
                [label 8] => value
                [label 9] => value
                [label 10] => value
                [label 11] => value
                [label 12] => value
                [label 13] => value
                [label 14] => value
                [label 15] => value
                [label 16] => value
                [label 17] => value
                [label 18] => value
                [label 19] => value
                [label 20] => value
)
```

I'm not sure how to get the str_getcsv to do this.  Maybe define the elements of the array before the str_getcsv function(not sure how to do this)???  Looking for something similar to an associative array...

Comment: `$rows[] = array_combine($array_with_keys,str_getcsv(...`

Comment: why `file` and `str_getcsv` instead of `fgetcsv`?

Comment: Well, this accomplishes the task at hand with this one exception.  I don't think the fgetcsv would handle this any differently...